In Remote Server Locally .xls file loading and downloading but in IIS deployment .xls file not load

`ExcelDownload.aspx.cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using NPOI.XSSF.UserModel;
using OBLLOANADVANCEModel;
using System.Reflection;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Diagnostics;
public partial class Admin_ExcelDownload : BasePage
{
#region reference
public dbCLDataContext dbCL = null;
public OBLLOANADVANCEEntities db = null;
UIUtility oUtility = new UIUtility();
public ProcessedBranch oProcessedBranch = null;
private static Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook mWorkBook;
private static Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Sheets mWorkSheets;
private static Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet mWSheet1;
private static Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application oXL;
public XSSFWorkbook wb;
public XSSFSheet sh;
public string qualitativejudge = null;
public int quarter = 0, year = 0;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if (!IsPostBack)
{
if (CheckEndSession())
Response.Redirect("~/admin/AdminDefault.aspx");
oUtility = new UIUtility();
db = new OBLLOANADVANCEEntities();
        //GenerateTemplate();

var ConbranchList = db.vwConfirmBranches.Where(x => x.IsActive == true).ToList();
var branchList = db.Branch.Where(x => x.IsActive == true).ToList();
var processedBranchList = db.vwProcessedBranch.Where(x => x.IsActive == true).ToList();
oUtility.FillCombo(ddlBranch, "Name", "BranchCode", branchList, true, false);
oUtility.FillCombo(ddlCerBranch, "Name", "BranchCode", ConbranchList, true, false);
if (ConbranchList.Count>0)


dbCL = new dbCLDataContext();
SoftwareConfig objSoftwareConfig=new SoftwareConfig();
objSoftwareConfig = dbCL.SoftwareConfigs.Where(p => p.Type == 1).FirstOrDefault();
if (objSoftwareConfig.IsActive == true)
{
btnDownload.Enabled = true;
}
else
{
btnDownload.Enabled = false;
}
    }
}

protected void btnExportExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
GenerateLoanExcelAndSave();
}
private void GenerateLoanExcelAndSave()
{
oProcessedBranch = new ProcessedBranch();
var branchCode = Session["CurrentUserBranchCode"].ToString();


branchCode = ddlBranch.SelectedValue.ToString();
}
db = new OBLLOANADVANCEEntities();
try
{
string logText = @"Path";
List CLLoanDetailList = null;
if (branchCode == "501")
{
CLLoanDetailList = db.CLLoanDetail.Where(x => x.SB_IsActive == true && x.SB_Amount > 0).OrderBy(x => x.SB_ID).ToList();
}
else
{
CLLoanDetailList = db.CLLoanDetail.Where(x => (x.SB_OBLBranchCode == branchCode) && x.SB_IsActive == true && x.SB_Amount > 0).OrderBy(x => x.SB_ID).ToList();
}
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(logText, true))
{
String msg = "Checking Done";
sw.WriteLine(msg);
}
CLLoanDetailList = CLLoanDetailList.Where(x => x.LoanNature == "1" || x.LoanNature == "2" || x.LoanNature == "3" || x.LoanNature == "14").ToList();
CLLoanDetailList =
CLLoanDetailList.Where(x => x.LoanCategory == "10" || x.LoanCategory == "8" || x.LoanCategory == "7" || x.LoanCategory == "6" || x.LoanCategory == "11")
.ToList();
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(logText, true))
{
String msg = "Data Load in List";
sw.WriteLine(msg);
}
string CLExcel_path = @"Path + ".xls";
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(logText, true))
{
String msg = "Excel File Location";
sw.WriteLine(msg);
}
oXL = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
oXL.Visible = true;
oXL.DisplayAlerts = false;
mWorkBook = oXL.Workbooks.Open(CLExcel_path, 0, false, 5, "", "", false, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "", true, false, 0, true, false, false);




}

}
`The entire application run and executed in same server locally. But when try in IIS 10 .xls file not load. This is Isolated server. (Excel v:2007 and windos 2019 server). What should I do now?`


This may be a permissions issue. Please check whether your iis has permission to access the location of the .xls file.

Thank you -Samwu. Create C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\desktop is worked for me. I don't have an idea why using desktop folder in systemprofile.

You can try moving the desktop folder to the system configuration file path.
